# Mean of truncated gamma distribution using threshold

Tags: descriptive-statistics, gamma-distribution, truncated-distributions

Given a gamma distribution with PDF:

$f(x;\alpha;\beta) = \frac{x^{\alpha-1} e^{-\frac{x}{\beta}}}{\Gamma(\alpha) \beta^\alpha}$

with a shape parameter $\alpha > 0$, a scale parameter $\beta > 0$ and $\Gamma(k)$ the gamma function.

The mean is then $\alpha\beta$ and variance $\alpha\beta^2$, hence

$\alpha = \frac{1}{Var(X) \lambda^2},\ \beta = Var(X) \lambda\  $

Samples from this gamma distribution are divided into 2 classes, samples smaller than a certain threshold `T`, and samples larger than or equal to `T`.

What is the mean of class 1 and class 2, in this case?

Comment: Presumably $f$ is the PDF and $x \gt 0.$  Essentially by definition, the answers must be expressed in terms of the incomplete Gamma function, except when $\alpha$ is a small integer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\mathscr{C}_1$ and $\mathscr{C}_2$ denote classes 1 and 2 respectively.  Since $X \sim \text{Ga}(\alpha, \beta)$ you have:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
\mathbb{E}(X | X \in \mathscr{C}_1) = \mathbb{E}(X | X < T) 
&= \frac{\mathbb{E}(X \cdot \mathbb{I}(X < T))}{\mathbb{P}(X < T)}  \\[6pt]
&= \frac{ \int_0^T x \cdot \text{Ga}(x|\alpha, \beta) dx }{ \int_0^T \text{Ga}(x|\alpha, \beta) dx } \\[6pt]
&= \frac{ \int_0^T x^\alpha e^{-x/\beta} dx }{ \int_0^T x^{\alpha-1} e^{-x/\beta} dx } \\[6pt]
&= \beta \cdot \frac{ \int_0^T (x/\beta)^\alpha e^{-x/\beta} dx }{ \int_0^T (x/\beta)^{\alpha-1} e^{-x/\beta} dx } \\[6pt]
&= \beta \cdot\frac{ \int_0^{T/\beta} y^\alpha e^{-y} dy }{ \int_0^{T/\beta} y^{\alpha-1} e^{-y} dy } \\[6pt]
&= \beta \cdot\frac{ \gamma(\alpha+1,T/\beta) }{ \gamma(\alpha,T/\beta) }, \\[6pt]
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

where $\gamma$ is the [lower incomplete beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function).  Similarly, you have:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
\mathbb{E}(X | X \in \mathscr{C}_2) = \mathbb{E}(X | X \geqslant T) 
&= \frac{\mathbb{E}(X \cdot \mathbb{I}(X \geqslant T))}{\mathbb{P}(X \geqslant T)} \\[6pt]
&= \frac{ \int_T^\infty x \cdot \text{Ga}(x|\alpha, \beta) dx }{ \int_T^\infty \text{Ga}(x|\alpha, \beta) dx } \\[6pt]
&= \frac{ \int_T^\infty x^\alpha e^{-x/\beta} dx }{ \int_T^\infty x^{\alpha-1} e^{-x/\beta} dx } \\[6pt]
&= \beta \cdot \frac{ \int_T^\infty (x/\beta)^\alpha e^{-x/\beta} dx }{ \int_T^\infty (x/\beta)^{\alpha-1} e^{-x/\beta} dx } \\[6pt]
&= \beta \cdot\frac{ \int_{T/\beta}^\infty y^\alpha e^{-y} dy }{ \int_{T/\beta}^\infty y^{\alpha-1} e^{-y} dy } \\[6pt]
&= \beta \cdot\frac{ \Gamma(\alpha+1,T/\beta) }{ \Gamma(\alpha,T/\beta) }, \\[6pt]
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

where $\Gamma$ is the [upper incomplete gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function).

Comment: The ratio of the two incomplete gamma functions can be changed into an expression with a single incomplete gamma function using the property

$$\gamma(\alpha+1,T) = \alpha\gamma(\alpha,T)-T^\alpha e^{-T}$$

such that we can write $\mathbb{E}f_T(x)$ also like:

$$\mathbb{E}f_T(x) = \beta \frac{\gamma(\alpha+1,T)}{\gamma(\alpha,T)}
= \beta \left( \alpha - \frac{T^\alpha e^T}{ \gamma(\alpha,T) }\right)
$$

Comment: Fair enough, though I'm not convinced that that form is any simpler.

Comment: I do not know anymore why I came up with that 'simplification' 5 years ago. Possibly I just saw the ratio with only the small and integer valued difference in the parameters $\alpha$ and $\alpha +1$ and was curious whether that could be simplified. Well that final function has a gamma function less, but it is indeed not particularly simpler. Nowadays I would stress the $\alpha\beta$ term and write it as $$\beta\alpha  -  \frac{\beta T^\alpha e^T}{ \gamma(\alpha,T)}$$

Answer (score 5):

I wanted to comment but I don't have enough reputation to comment. So I hope this will be allowed to stay as an "answer". There's an error in Ben's derivation: when switching variables from $x$ to $y=x/\beta$, the limit of integration $T$ needs to be changed to $T/\beta$ (so scale is taken out). Thus the result (also using Sextus Empiricus's simplification) is
$$\mathbb{E}[X\mid X<T]=\beta\cdot\frac{\gamma(\alpha+1,T/\beta)}{\gamma(\alpha,T/\beta)}=\beta\left(\alpha-\frac{(T/\beta)^\alpha e^{-T/\beta}}{\gamma(\alpha,T/\beta)}\right).$$
That is, truncation at $T$ reduces the mean by $\displaystyle\beta\frac{(T/\beta)^\alpha e^{-T/\beta}}{\gamma(\alpha,T/\beta)}$.

Ben, your answer is accepted, so if you see this, could you edit your answer?

**EDIT AFTER A FEW DAYS:** I just realized that we can also write the truncated mean as
$$\mathbb E[X\mid X<T]=\alpha\beta\left[1-\beta\cdot\frac{\text{pdf}(T;\alpha+1,\beta)}{\text{cdf}(T;\alpha,\beta)}\right].$$
This form may be easier for computation using pdf/cdf functions (I am thinking R).
It's also intuitive: if we take $T$ to $\infty$, the second term in brackets vanishes, and we recover the Gamma mean $\alpha\beta$.

Comment: Thanks for this correction --- I did not see it until today.  My answer is now corrected.